# Which file types is CodeIgniters File Helper able to read?

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-type

Right now I'm deciding if CodeIgniter provides me the tools I need. But to decide that I need to know which file types CodeIgniters File Helper can read?

Which of the following file types can it read?

- bmp
- doc
- docx
- gif
- jpg
- odt
- pdf
- png
- ppt
- pptx
- rtf
- txt
- xls
- xlsx

I want to be able to read these file types so that I can display them in the browser using PHP.
I was not able to find something which tells me which file types the File Helper can read, I hope someone will be able to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `mimes.php` in `application/config` folder. See the full list.